# ruby on rails year select issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my code looks like this

```
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :date_of_birth  %><br />
  <%= date_select :date_of_birth, {order: [:month, :day, :year], 
    prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, 
    start_year:1950, end_year: Date.today.year}, {required: true}, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

And result is in this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyH1N.jpg)

What i want that year selection be from 1950 to now.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works perfectly for me:

```
<%= f.date_select( :date_of_birth, { :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => 1950, :end_year => Date.today.year }, { :required => true, :class => "form-control" }) %>
```

Note that my `date_select` control is prepended with `f`, for the form it belongs to... I think that might be your problem.

Comment: Now i get error "undefined method `date_of_birth' for #<User:0x007fe040e37920>". What can be wrong?

Comment: So... do you have a column called `date_of_birth` in your `users` table? Take a look at `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: No, i don't have it. I'm still new in ruby on rails, can you help me with that?

Comment: Well... each field in a form typically corresponds with a column in your table, so if you have `form_for(user)`, each component (like `f.text_field`, `f.date_select` etc. represents one of the columns in the user table. You need to write a [`migration`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) to add the `date_of_birth` column to your `users` table.